# Deploying java web application with javadoc as welcome-file

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created java web application. When i deploy my applicaton to server using tomcat7, i want to deploy my javadoc as welcome-file so when i go to root directory of app i want to see reference. But instead tomcate gives lots of 404 error. Here is my project structure;

[image]

And my web.xml is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Multiple packages, separated by semicolon(;), can be specified in param-value</description>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.elhan.usermanager</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>javadoc/index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind. I solved the problem by moving javadoc contents to "Web Pages" directory. And in the web.xml file i changed `javadoc/index.html` with `index.html`and deployed it. It works.